# Widget changing hangs the main window in GTK+

Tags: gtk, vala

I am writing a program in Vala using GTK+. It has a function that creates a ListBox that contains a lot of EventBox objects. There is one issue: there is one function that downloads the image and it takes a lot of time, so the main window didn't show up unless all downloads are finished. This is not what I wanted, I wanted main window to appear and then images to download and to be shown. So I separated image load to separate function, but main window still doesn't show unless all downloads are finished. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the function I'm using:

```
foreach (MediaInfo post in feedPosts)  
     feedList.prepend(post);

foreach (PostBox box in feedList.boxes)
     box.loadImage();
```

("feedList" is a class inherited from Gtk.ListBox and "boxes" is a list containing all of PostBox (which is inherited from Gtk.EventBox) objects)

This is feedList.prepend function:

```
public void append(MediaInfo post)
{
    Gtk.Separator separator = new Gtk.Separator (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL);
    base.prepend(separator);
    PostBox box = new PostBox(post);
    base.prepend(box);
    boxes.append(box);      
}
```

And this is the constructor and loadImage functions of PostBox class:

```
public PostBox(MediaInfo post)
{
    box = new Gtk.Box(Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, 0);
    this.add(box);

    this.post = post;

    userToolbar = new Gtk.Box (Gtk.Orientation.HORIZONTAL, 0);

    userNameLabel = new Gtk.Label("@" + post.postedUser.username);
    this.userNameLabel.set_markup(
            "<span underline='none' font_weight='bold' size='large'>" +
            post.postedUser.username + "</span>"
            );


    userToolbar.add(userNameLabel);
    box.pack_start(userToolbar, false, true);   

    image = new Gtk.Image();
    box.add(image); 

    box.add(new Gtk.Label(post.title));
    box.add(new Gtk.Label( post.likesCount.to_string() + " likes."));
    print("finished.\n");

    return;
}   

public void loadImage()
{
    var imageFileName = PhotoStream.App.CACHE_URL + getFileName(post.image.url);
    downloadFile(post.image.url, imageFileName);

    Pixbuf imagePixbuf = new Pixbuf.from_file(imageFileName);   
    imagePixbuf = imagePixbuf.scale_simple(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, Gdk.InterpType.BILINEAR);


    image.set_from_pixbuf(imagePixbuf);             
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all my *async* methods with multithreading and now it is working the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You have written the download operations in another method, however the operations are still *synchronous*, i.e. they **block the thread**. You never want to do computationaly or otherwise expensive things in the GUI thread, because that makes the GUI unresponsive.

You should start your downloads *asynchronously*, and trigger a *callback method* when the download is complete. In the callback, then you may for example change the image placeholders to actual images.

Comment: I thought moving image downloading code from the PostBox constructor to separate function would make this, but apparently this isn't working the way I want it to work.

Comment: Can you show me how it should be handled? Because I can't understand how to do it properly.

Comment: You should check these out: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/AsyncSamples, also there is a section about it here: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Tutorial#Asynchronous_Methods

Comment: I tried to rewrite second "foreach" statement this way: http://pastebin.com/9bzgBrKm, but the result is the same.

Comment: You should define an `async` method to download an image form an URL. Call its `begin` with the URL parameter, and define the callback. I could write a more complex example tomorrow, but not right now.

Comment: @meskobalasz I rewrote my loadImage function this way: http://pastebin.com/cjzaMs0V (if I declare loadImage not as async, the program simply doesn't work) and leave second "foreach" statement as it was, still the same result.

Comment: I don't understand this but I removed "async" from loadImage declaration and it still worked, although id didn't worked earlier. But anyway, now all the app icon is shown among running apps, but when I click it, window doesn't show, unless all downloads are finished, then it shows the window.